# How to show user name after login in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to show user name after login in **codeigniter**?

```
<?php

class Users_model extends CI_Model {

    function validate($user_name, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('user_name', $user_name);
        $this->db->where('pass_word', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('membership');      
        if($query->num_rows >= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }       
    }

    function get_db_session_data()
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('user_data')->get('ci_sessions');
        $user = array(); /* array to store the user data we fetch */
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $udata = unserialize($row->user_data);
            /* put data in array using username as key */
            $user['user_name'] = $udata['user_name']; 
            $user['is_logged_in'] = $udata['is_logged_in']; 
        }
        return $user;
    }

    function create_member()
    {

        $this->db->where('user_name', $this->input->post('username'));
        $query = $this->db->get('membership');

        if($query->num_rows > 0){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>';
            echo "Username already taken";  
            echo '</strong></div>';
        }else{

            $new_member_insert_data = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'email_addres' => $this->input->post('email_address'),          
                'user_name' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'pass_word' => md5($this->input->post('password'))                      
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data);
            return $insert;
        }

    }//create_member

    function login()
    {

        $this->db->where('user_name', $this->input->post('username'));
        $query = $this->db->get('membership');

        if($query->num_rows > 0){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>';
            echo "Username already taken";  
            echo '</strong></div>';
        }else{

            $new_member_insert_data = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'email_addres' => $this->input->post('email_address'),          
                'user_name' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'pass_word' => md5($this->input->post('password'))                      
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data);
            return $insert;
        }

    }//create_member    
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us the code you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

Well, when you login a user, make sure to store the username in the session using
`$this->session->set_userdata('username', 'Your user name');`

Call the username in your view using
`echo $this->session->userdata('username');`

Comment: @MalikMudassar Remove above comment.

Answer (score 0):

class Users_model extends CI_Model {

```
function validate($user_name, $password)
{
    $this->db->where('user_name', $user_name);
    $this->db->where('pass_word', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('membership');      
    if($query->num_rows >= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }       
}

function get_db_session_data()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('user_data')->get('ci_sessions');
    $user = array(); /* array to store the user data we fetch */
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $udata = unserialize($row->user_data);
        /* put data in array using username as key */
        $user['user_name'] = $udata['user_name']; 
        $user['is_logged_in'] = $udata['is_logged_in']; 
    }
    return $user;
}

function create_member()
{

    $this->db->where('user_name', $this->input->post('username'));
    $query = $this->db->get('membership');

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>';
        echo "Username already taken";  
        echo '</strong></div>';
    }else{

        $new_member_insert_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email_addres' => $this->input->post('email_address'),          
            'user_name' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'pass_word' => md5($this->input->post('password'))                      
        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data);
        return $insert;
    }

}//create_member

function login()
{

    $this->db->where('user_name', $this->input->post('username'));
    $query = $this->db->get('membership');

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>';
        echo "Username already taken";  
        echo '</strong></div>';
    }else{

        $new_member_insert_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email_addres' => $this->input->post('email_address'),          
            'user_name' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'pass_word' => md5($this->input->post('password'))                      
        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data);
        return $insert;
    }

}//create_member
```

}

Comment: This is not a answer you can re edit your own question by clicking on edit button below tags.